# Missing return statement Challenge.java:7

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I am running this java code and I am getting an error

> /Challenge.java:7: error: missing return statement

```java
public class Challenge {

    public static boolean isEqual(int num1, int num2) {
        if( num1 == num2 )
            return true;    
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println( isEqual( 8, 8 ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `return` statement in every branch of the method. In the `isEqual` method, if the `if`'s condition isn't met, you don't have a `return` statement. You could add one:

```java
public static boolean isEqual(int num1, int num2) {
    if ( num1 == num2 )
        return true;
    return false; // Here!    
}
```

Or, even simpler, you could return the `==` expression directly and avoid the problem altogether:

```java
public static boolean isEqual(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 == num2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add return statement if num1 != num2 like this

```
public static boolean isEqual(int num1, int num2) {

if( num1 == num2 )
    {return true;}
return false;

}
```